# How to display a gallery of images placed on the screen with vue-image-lightbox

Tags: vue.js

### Overview

Thank you for browsing.
I am using vue-image-lightbox to create a gallery view.
I completed the installation of vue-image-lightbox by looking at other blogs.
I was able to install it.
but I'm having trouble figuring out how to display a gallery of images that are displayed on the screen, which is the movement I really want to do!

### Detail

The movement we are aiming for is to
The movement we are aiming for is to display two images in the gallery, surrounded by figure tags.
(The media in the script tag is just a sample that contains data.)

The current code is as follows.
Show.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <figure>
      <a class="img-box" href="" data-lightbox="image" data-title="#">
        <img
            :src="#"
            :alt="#"
        >
      </a>
      <figcaption class="mt-3">test1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a class="img-box" href="" data-lightbox="image" data-title="#">
        <img
            :src="#"
            :alt="#"
        >
      </a>
      <figcaption class="mt-3">test2</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <ImageLightBox :media="media" ref="lightbox" :show-light-box="false" :show-caption="true"></ImageLightBox>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import ImageLightBox from 'vue-image-lightbox';

require("vue-image-lightbox/dist/vue-image-lightbox.min.css");

export default {
  name: 'lightbox',
  components: {
    ImageLightBox,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      media: [
        {
          thumb: 'https://www.pakutaso.com/shared/img/thumb/YAMAhokkaido015_TP_V.jpg',
          src: 'https://www.pakutaso.com/shared/img/thumb/YAMAhokkaido015_TP_V.jpg',
        },
        {
          thumb: 'https://www.pakutaso.com/shared/img/thumb/YAMAhokkaido032_TP_V.jpg',
          src: 'https://www.pakutaso.com/shared/img/thumb/YAMAhokkaido032_TP_V.jpg',
        },
        {
          thumb: 'https://www.pakutaso.com/shared/img/thumb/KMKC428D354_TP_V.jpg',
          src: 'https://www.pakutaso.com/shared/img/thumb/KMKC428D354_TP_V.jpg',
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
</script>
```